# Setting white-space to "nowrap" for paragraph on page, ruins fixed positioning in mobile browsers

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

The steps to replicate this problem are a bit cumbersome, but for those who care, please help me solve this mystery.

Try it with any of the bootstrap themes. For example http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/

In the Google Chrome Inspector, toggle the device to view it in a mobile view. The nav-bar remains fixed to the top as it is scrolled. This is as expected.
[image: nav bar remains fixed while scrolling the page]

However set some paragraph's css to be {white-space: "nowrap"}. The nav-bar no longer remains fixed but scrolls with the rest of the page.

[image: nav bar scrolls away with the page]

It took me forever to identify this unsuspecting culprit. Does anybody know why this is happening?

```css
p {
    white-space: nowrap;/* this ruins the layout in the mobile browser */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

    <title>Fixed Top Navbar Example for Bootstrap</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <link href="../../assets/css/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/navbar-fixed-top.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy these 2 lines! -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <script src="../../assets/js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>

  <body>

    <!-- Fixed navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="../navbar/">Default</a></li>
            <li><a href="../navbar-static-top/">Static top</a></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="./">Fixed top <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">

      <!-- Main component for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
      <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Navbar example</h1>
        <p>This example is a quick exercise to illustrate how the default, static and fixed to top navbar work. It includes the responsive CSS and HTML, so it also adapts to your viewport and device.</p>
        <p>To see the difference between static and fixed top navbars, just scroll.</p>
        <p>
          <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="../../components/#navbar" role="button">View navbar docs &raquo;</a>
        </p>
      </div>

    </div> <!-- /container -->


    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../../assets/js/vendor/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <script src="../../dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <script src="../../assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Out of curiousity, why are you using `white-space: nowrap;` there in particular? But anyway, the reason is that because the navbar is `position: fixed;` it makes it 100% width of the space that is used to contain the text so it's expanding the body tag.

As to why it's not scrolling, it is quite strange because *the fixed attribute is essentially getting ignored when you scroll down but is fine when scrolling up*.

This CSS below fixed it, although it simply cuts of the text rather than letting it spill over.

```
.jumbotron {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Here is some more information on the [position attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/position).

Comment: That was helpful. I guess we may not understand the strange behavior, but it brings a little more clarity.